Nginx doesnt run in windows 7 sp1 , no error messages
I am trying to run nginx 1.3.1 on windows 7 sp1 and it doesnt start , no error messages. Nothing.
I checked the error log in nginx , sometimes it says its starting the application , sometimes nothing. I checked windows event viewer nothing there also.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Running nginx.exe (either by CLI or just double clicking) without additional parameters makes it run silently in the background. You can check if it's running correctly by typing "localhost" in your browser address bar.
Test configuration file using:
nginx -t
Test nginx version using:
nginx -v
